# can't pass object as a prop React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

UPDATED: I added the whole code of the parent component. The idea is to get data from coponent DarbaiLT, store that data in the object named 'objektas'. Then to pass that data as a prop to component AnObject.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import DarbaiLT from "./DarbaiLT";
import AnObject from './AnObject';

 const objektas = {
  name: 'hello',
}

class App extends Component {

  onObjectClick = (darbas) => {
    objektas.value = darbas;    
    console.log('objektas: ', objektas.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/object" exact component={AnObject} />
            <DarbaiLT onObjectClick={this.onObjectClick} />
            <AnObject info={objektas}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I console.log it and it still gives undefined. I also am using Router and Switch, but that shouldn't be any difference right?

```
import React from "react";

const AnObject =(props)=> {
  console.log(props.info);
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <img src='../images/slide4.jpg' width="100%" />
        </div>
      </>
    );
}

export default AnObject;
```

Comment: [It works just fine for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-dewdney-v75kv?file=/src/anobject.js), so I'm assuming you didn't properly export/import

Comment: Nothing's wrong in this code, it should work, either you call an AnObject from another component, not from App either you redefined it inside App component, otherwise it should work

Comment: can you please a codesandbox for the same. This should ideally work.

Comment: why you don't wrap your DarbaiLT & AnObject into a Route in Switch?

Comment: If you want to share data between components, its better to use something like Redux or react Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I don't fully understand Redux yet, so I avoided it and wanted to use callback functions and props. Do you maybe have an idea why it isn't working? Or it still works for you?